# Error Installing Docker Desktop for Windows 10

Tags: docker-desktop

```
Failed to start service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
   at CommunityInstaller.Service.Service.<StartAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.Service.Manager.<AddServiceAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I'm getting this error during install - the previous install hung and then onwards it does not complete successfully.  Any idea how to repair this or cleanup and restart?

```
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction.<DoAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, with nothing but an error stack trace, there's really not enough here to go on. Also, this really isn't a programming question; it's more of a software installation issue - maybe reach out to Docker for support?

Comment: Sounds good - I shall ask Docker.

Comment: I fixed a similar issue by resetting the WMI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239121/unble-to-install-docker-desktop-on-windows-10-pro-21h1/70382173#70382173

Answer (score 22):

Disabling the power service worked for me too.

1. Open msconfig.exe in the windows menu bar
2. Go to the "services" tab
3. Start typing "power" and it will auto find the correct service.
4. Untick the checkbox
5. Restart your PC
6. Make sure you do not have any Docker installation files in your drive
7. Start the installation process again and hopefully that'll work for you

Comment: Not worked for me. In my case error is like - Download failed: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\u2gf2kdqqcm'.
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()

Comment: If this works or not, make sure to ENABLE the "Power" service again after Docker installation attempt. (The Power service handles, you guessed it, the Power Plan of your PC, so it needs to actually be running normally.)

Comment: Perfect. Working until version 4.11.1.

Comment: @john anything workng for you?  this did not work for me either

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and seemed to start happening after the lasted window update.

I manage to solve the issue by stopping and disabling the "power" (Power management) window service. I did repeat the process two times and seemed to be a consistent issue, at least in my case. Be sure this service is not running, at least in my case it worked, hope this helps.

Some references:
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6091

Comment: i have unchecked it, but yet i am not able to install docker using the installer. i don't know what to do. i still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone getting this error:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed
```

The fix for me was enabling this service:

```
Windows Modules Installer
```

Note I used a tool [1] to do this, but I think you can also just use the normal Services App.

1. https://github.com/WereDev/Wu10Man

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything (reboot, different versions 2.5, 3.0, 3.3, power, disabling real-time protection). Only increasing timeout helped me:

1. Click Start, click Run, type Regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
4. In the right pane, locate the ServicesPipeTimeout entry.
   Note If the ServicesPipeTimeout entry does not exist, you must create it. To do this, follow these steps:

- On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
- Type ServicesPipeTimeout, and then press ENTER.

5. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify.
6. Click decimal, type 60000, and then click OK.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what that is doing to someone who understand just the basics about operating systems?

Comment: Mine was at 120000, so that's probably not it in my case....

Comment: strangely ServicesPipeTimeout   doesn't exist in my registry

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while installing Docker 3.5.0

*Download failed: Could not find a part of the path ‘C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\rzsiezg3p2h’. at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()*

I resolved it by following these steps.

1. Download and install docker **2.5.0.1**
2. After installation open docker desktop.
3. A pop-up appears to update docker to **3.4.0** (or later), click update.
4. Once updated you are ready to launch and play with docker desktop.

Alternately you can try downloading and installing docker 3.4.0 directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue and needed to do the following:

1. Uninstall.
2. If there are any leftovers, you should:

   - Run the **RegEdit** with **Admin Rights**.
   - Delete all remaining entries of **Docker Desktop**.

After this, I was able to install it properly. Also, I have noticed in my case, this situation has become repetitive in every update.

**P.S.:**

The power idea proposed in the previous answers didn't work in my case. Somehow, the installation got corrupted and couldn't run. This has happened more than once after Docker tries to update.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was related to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/127

A different version of NLog from the windows GAC was interfering with the one that comes with the docker installation.

To resolve this the version in the GAC has to be deleted:

1. go to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly
2. find the folder NLog
3. delete it

Answer (score 1):

Docker components require a compatibility layer for running Linux binary executables natively on Windows 10 and Windows 11.( When you opt for "install required components for WSL2" ).Try installing WSL before installing docker on your system. To install WSL and Docker, follow these steps~

1. Right click on CMD (Command Prompt)
2. Run as administration
3. Enter the following command~

> `wsl --install`
> 4. After completion, restart your computer
> 5. Try reinstalling docker

Before installing WSL, make sure your windows version is updated.

Refer this link to [install WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Comment: `Running as administrator` worked for me (didn't need to do anything else.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I saw some comments regarding overall installation issues, I have separated a link with the main issues faced while installing Docker Desktop for Windows 10

1. One of the main problems is a permission issue related to the WindowsApps folder - When WSL 2 failed to start with the **access denied** error. *The article below shows **how to solve that***:
   https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/

*More discussions about other related access-denied issues below:*
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/kb4565503-installed-then-wsl-2-failed-to-start/25794c4f-0b20-465e-bbdb-a8af3d9e0e88?auth=1

2. Install Docker Desktop using some of these step-by-step guides:
   https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-wsl2-windows-10

*A good alternative one*: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-wsl2-on-windows-10

3. In case you are facing some CPU/memory consumption issue in Windows, these settings could help
   https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/how-to-stop-wsl2-from-hogging-all-your-ram-with-docker-d7846b9c5b37
4. Probably you will face this issue regarding disk space, in that case, take a look at this thread on Github
   https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699

Answer (score 0):

> component communityinstaller.enablefeaturesaction failed: invalid
> namespace at communityinstaller.installworkflow.d_29.movenext() ---
> end of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.throw() at
> system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.handlenonsuccessanddebuggernotification(task
> task) at communityinstaller.installworkflow.d_23.movenext()

If this is the issue while installing the Docker desktop in windows

[image: While installing docker desktop, by default WSL2 and Add shortcut to desktop is ticked or checked as shown in image]

Ans:- uncheck the first configuration from the image (i.e 'Install required Windows components for WSL 2')

Answer (score 0):

I am late to answer but I am able to solve this issue using simple fix.
This is valid if you have recently upgraded your Windows OS to latest version.

1. Open Windows in Safe Mode
2. go to run and type ->  RegEdit
3. Traverse to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysPlant
4. Now change **Start**  value to 4.
5. Restart and try to install docker now.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Windows 10 using Windows 10 Update Assistant, and the docker got installed.

(The update was from version 19042.1237 to 19043.1237)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following folders and try again

- C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\Docker
- C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop
- C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Docker

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).

For me, docker started crashing and I uninstalled in (sadly unproperly). For 5 days I have struggled with this docker issue but this command worked like a charm for 4.23.0.

Running this command in cmd as Administrator fixes the problem :

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```