# Having trouble installing Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I tried to install docker desktop but it giving me this error. WSL2 is installed and enabled in my desktop. Virtulization is enabled in my desktop. Please help me with this issue.
[component communityinstaller.enablefeaturesaction failed: invalid namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPt3a.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**Check this items :**

- [Enable Virtual Machine feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature)
- [Download and Install the Linux kernel update package](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)
- Set WSL 2 as your default version `wsl --set-default-version 2`
- Set your distribution version to WSL 2 `wsl --set-version <distribution name> 2`

**Edit**

If this method does not fix your problem, you might need to use **This PC Reset**.

Comment: Tried all these things already but it didn't work

Comment: @JayGandhi are you installing docker from https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows ?

Comment: Yes I installed from same link

Comment: @JayGandhi Check this methods : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811392/error-installing-docker-desktop-for-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare the lastet install file(download from official website)
2. Go to **Windows Services** (you can launch by **services.msc**)
3. Find out the service "**Docker Desktop Service**", then stop it manually.
4. Execute the install file you prepared.
5. Expected it will install well.

ref from my blog **[Docker Desktop Upgrade Failed](https://mattmytech.blogspot.com/2021/10/docker-desktop-upgrade-failed.html)**