# Unable to install Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Pro 21H1

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am trying to install Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Pro 21H1, but I'm constantly getting the below error:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: Not found 
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

I have tried deleting:

```
C:\Program Files\
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Docker
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Docker Desktop
```

... and other Docker related folders multiple times.

I have WSL2 running fine on my system with Ubuntu 20.

```
sid_c06@LAPTOP-HJCDC6N0:~$ wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
```

I tried unchecking the WSL2 option during installation but then the step of starting Linux Containers on WSL2 fails when trying to start Docker Desktop after installation.

```
Unable to start
at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup)
at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.b__0()
at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

Can you let me know what am I doing wrong? Also should I go with installing Docker directly on Ubuntu on WSL2 and skip Docker Desktop? I couldn't find concreate steps for same. Let me know if that is a good idea.

Comment: Not that it helps but I encounter the exact same problem and pulling my hears out for 3 days now. Great start for learning Docker, it just doesn't work. Well, into the bin with it.

Comment: Hi, Just if it helps. I had uninstalled everything related to docker from AppData etc and then downgraded the version to 5.7.3 and it's working fine now.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows completely. I had the luxury because It was reinstalled a few weeks ago. This got it to work. But it is not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is usually with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

Running this command in cmd as Administrator fixes the problem :

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```

Hope it works for you too. In my case, docker started crashing and I uninstalled in (sadly unproperly). For 5 days I have struggled with this docker issue but this command worked like a charm for 4.23.0.

Answer (score 5):

I performed many actions to solve it which are listed below. I believe that resetting the WMI was the key action, though.

1. I deleted all remaining Docker/Docker Desktop folders in Windows:

   ```
   ~/AppData/Local/Docker
   ~/AppData/Roaming/Docker
   C:\ProgramData\Docker
   C:\Program Files\Docker
   ```
2. I also uninstalled and installed back the following windows features:

   - `Hyper-V`
   - `Windows Subsystem Linux`
   - `Windows Hypervision Platform`.
3. Disabled Windows Service `Power`
4. Reset the WMI

   - Disable and stop the WMI service:

     ```
     sc config winmgmt start= disabled
     net stop winmgmt
     ```
   - Run the following commands:

     ```
     Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
     Winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem
     ```
   - Re-enable the WMI service and reboot:

     ```
     sc config winmgmt start= auto
     ```

     *(note that there is a blank between '=' and 'auto')*

If the problem remains, then try the following steps to rebuild the repository:

1. Disable and stop the WMI service

   ```
   sc config winmgmt start= disabled     
   net stop winmgmt
   ```

   *(note that there is a blank between '=' and 'disabled')*
2. Rename the repository folder (located at `%windir%\System32\wbem\repository`) to `repository.old`
3. Re-enable the WMI service

   ```
   sc config winmgmt start= auto
   ```
4. Reboot the machine.

Reference [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1152280/get-net-powershell-cmdlets-failing-with-invalid-class?answertab=votes#tab-top)