# Docker Windows 10 installation Error Component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction failed: Process InstallerCli.exe exited

Tags: windows-10, docker-desktop

I get below error when try to install Docker Desktop for Windows 4.0.0

```
Component CommunityInstaller.ExecAction failed: Process InstallerCli.exe exited with code 1
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Tried lower version (`3.6.0`) as well, but same result.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811392/error-installing-docker-desktop-for-windows-10  Have you tried this?

Comment: @matdon I tried that and didn't help.

Comment: Version `3.4.0 ` version worked without any issue. I can't update the version it seems.

Comment: Hey, buddy you help me a lot. I have try to disable power and some way to change Regedit. None or action is work. Only download version 3.4.0. Attached my windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise Version : 20H2

Comment: i'm have installed windows 10 build 18362.356 and Docker says me what this build is deprecated and i'm need upgrade my windows for using latest Docker.
in my case i installed docker 3.4.0 and should not install doker updates

Comment: Hi! In my case stopping 'Docker Desktop Service' manually helped.

Comment: I getting the same error with version `4.4.3`

Comment: Version `3.4.0` worked for me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you had Docker for Desktop installed before on your machine**, the issue could be the security settings for the C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop folder which blocks modifications (writes, updates and delete operations) for any user and application. Since it is an application (Docker Desktop Installer) which needs to use that folder, you need to let "TrustedInstallers" write and modify this folder. You might also need to give full access to Administrator and System users since you most likely are running Docker Desktop Installer as Admin.

Answer (score 7):

this happened to me also.
Then, I also tried to install other versions, but it didn't work.

So, to fix this I just manually deleted the folders:

- C:\ProgramData\Docker
- C:\Program Files\Docker

After this, docker 4.6.0 was installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all Docker files in C:\ProgramData\ and C:\Program Files\ allowed me to install 4.6.0, before that I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and for 5 days, I tried to fix it, removed docker files, reinstalled WSL2, everything.The solution I have found is fixing Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and for this open cmd in Administrative mod and:

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```

Worked like a charm in 4.23.0. Hope it solves for other people who experience the same problem. I wasted too much time on this.